# How would one programmatically backup a Realm file?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I would like to be able to have my app save a backup copy of the Realm. How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RLMRealm`'s `-writeCopyToPath:` ([reference doc](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.88.0/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#//api/name/writeCopyToPath:error:)) method copies the Realm file to the given location in a compacted way.

Comment: Is there a reference doc for doing this in Swift? It looks like this doc is pointed towards objective-c.

Comment: Docs are Objective-C only for now. You can command-click on tokens to see their Swift interface though. We're even building a Swift documentation tool to address that very problem. https://github.com/realm/jazzy

Comment: Is the path supposed to be a path on my mac or in the virtual iOS device?

Comment: I just answered on the GitHub issue you just posted.